# Vue&TypeScript: возможно ли определить свойство el в библиотеках' vue-property-decorator/vue-class-component?

Tags: vue.js, typescript

Буду краток. Каков будет эквивалент для приведённого ниже кода на TypeScript-e c использованием библиотеки `vue-property-decorator` и её зависимости `vue-class-component`?

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

Comment: Вы разобрались с вопросом? Нашли решение?

Comment: @AlTheOne, на данный момент найдены [такие](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/is-el-property-defining-available-in-typescript-vue-property-decorator/42969) решения. Вероятно, кто-то добавит ещё более изящное решение.

Comment: Я как понимаю этот же способ будет корректно работать в @vue/cli 3 ?

Comment: @AlTheOne, честно: не проверял. Все используют разный набор инструментов с разными конфигурациями, да ещё и стили написания кода разные.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//App.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from "vue-class-component";
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

@Component<App>({
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        HelloWorld,
    }
})
export default class App extends Vue {
  tasks: number[] = [];
  /**
   **
   **/
 showAlert(){
   alert('Hello!');
 }
}
```

```html
<!--App.vue-->
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png" @click='showAlert'>
    <HelloWorld msg="Как собрать Vue проект с typesScript для unit тестов, и не сойти с ума"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" src="./App.ts"></script>
<style src="./App.css"></style>
```